pd.read_csv() not working with parse_dates
I'm using the Netflix Movies and TV Shows dataset to better understand pandas.
The column date_added is in the format: "September 21, 2024" which, as I understand, would be parsed as "%B-%d-%Y". Simply Reading with pd.read_csv() returns this column as an object type.
Using parse_dates=['date_added'] doesn't seem to work, and neither specifying the format. Here is my code:
df = pd.read_csv('netflix_titles.csv', parse_dates=['date_added'], date_format='%B-%d-%Y')
df.info()

resulting in:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 8807 entries, 0 to 8806
Data columns (total 12 columns):
 #   Column        Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------        --------------  ----- 
 0   show_id       8807 non-null   object
 1   type          8807 non-null   object
 2   title         8807 non-null   object
 3   director      6173 non-null   object
 4   cast          7982 non-null   object
 5   country       7976 non-null   object
 6   date_added    8797 non-null   object
 7   release_year  8807 non-null   int64 
 8   rating        8803 non-null   object
 9   duration      8804 non-null   object
 10  listed_in     8807 non-null   object
 11  description   8807 non-null   object
dtypes: int64(1), object(11)
memory usage: 825.8+ KB

What am I doing wrong?

For me pd.read_csv('netflix_titles.csv', parse_dates=['date_added']) works. df.info() gives datetime64[ns] type.

date_format of  "September 21, 2024" is not '%B-%d-%Y' but '%B %d, %Y'

I see several problems here.

incorrect date_format (as wrote @iBeMeltin and @ayki)
nan values
spaces in values

How to check:
df = pd.read_csv('netflix_titles.csv')
for rec in df.to_dict('records'):
    try:
        datetime.strptime(rec['date_added'], '%B %d, %Y')
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        print(rec)

# {'show_id': 's6067', 'type': 'TV Show', 'title': "A Young Doctor's Notebook and Other Stories", 'director': nan, 'cast': 'Daniel Radcliffe, Jon Hamm, Adam Godley, Christopher Godwin, Rosie Cavaliero, Vicki Pepperdine, Margaret Clunie, Tim Steed, Shaun Pye', 'country': 'United Kingdom', 'date_added': nan ...
# {'show_id': 's8756', 'type': 'TV Show', 'title': 'Women Behind Bars', 'director': nan, 'cast': nan, 'country': 'United States', 'date_added': ' November 1, 2016'...
...

How to fix:
df = pd.read_csv('netflix_titles.csv')
df['date_added'] = df['date_added'].fillna('January 1, 1970')           # default for nan. You can skip if you don't need all values ​​as datetime
df['date_added'] = df['date_added'].str.strip()                         # remove spaces
df['date_added'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_added'], format='%B %d, %Y') # convert to dt

df.info()

Output:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 8807 entries, 0 to 8806
Data columns (total 12 columns):
 #   Column        Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------        --------------  -----         
 0   show_id       8807 non-null   object        
 1   type          8807 non-null   object        
 2   title         8807 non-null   object        
 3   director      6173 non-null   object        
 4   cast          7982 non-null   object        
 5   country       7976 non-null   object        
 6   date_added    8807 non-null   datetime64[ns]
 7   release_year  8807 non-null   int64         
 8   rating        8803 non-null   object        
 9   duration      8804 non-null   object        
 10  listed_in     8807 non-null   object        
 11  description   8807 non-null   object        
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(1), object(10)
memory usage: 825.8+ KB


There's no need to fillna here because pd.to_datetime() can handle NaNs, unlike datetime.datetime.strptime(). In fact, there's almost never any reason to use the datetime module with Pandas, since Pandas includes all the tools you need. (e.g. pd.Timestamp instead of datetime.datetime)

@wjandrea I know. I added this just to demonstrate the entries

Sorry? Why are you using fillna then if you're aware that you don't need to use it?

What I'm trying to say is, the nan values aren't actually a problem, you're just using the wrong tool to analyze the data (i.e. datetime.datetime.strptime() instead of pd.to_datetime())

@wjandrea ok. thanks and all the best

You're not going to edit the answer?

try this
df = pd.read_csv('netflix_titles.csv')
df['date_added'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_added'], format='%B %d, %Y', errors='coerce')

df.info()


The problem lies with the date_format argument. You specified %B-%d-%Y which would be September-21-2024 but you need to specify %B %d, %Y
You can actually remove the date_format altogether since parse_dates will infer the format for you since the column is already in a standard format (e.g. "YYYY-MM-DD", "MM/DD/YYYY", "Month DD, YYYY", etc.).
Typically, you only need to specify a date format if your dates are not in a standard format that is easy to infer.
Your code should look like:
df = pd.read_csv('netflix_titles.csv', parse_dates=['date_added'], date_format='%B %d, %Y')

OR
df = pd.read_csv('netflix_titles.csv', parse_dates=['date_added'])


Some values for date_added in the dataset have a leading space. I assume different pandas versions deal different with this. Using pandas 2.2.3 the solution of iBeMeltin does not work for me. However
pd.to_datetime(df['date_added'].str.strip(), format='%B %d, %Y')

works.
